# COM Interop Through Wine in OSX

Tags: c#, macos, office-interop, com-interop, wine

I am trying to write a program that modifies Office files (word, excel) programmatically using C#. Before continuing with my project, I would like to know if the COM Interop can be used in OSX by utilizing Wine, and if so, can this be done in Linux as well?

Comment: I've done it on Linux (11? maybe), but as far as working very well, it did not. My application would sometimes throw odd errors, and was very SLOW.

Comment: @jac did you try it on OSX or Linux? And also how long ago was this?

Comment: This sounds like a really flaky solution, not to mention that straight-up COM interop in C# is a PITA. If I were you, I'd look for C# libraries to work with Word/Excel documents like [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com).