# Is it possible to create a Excel-COM visible class library to use in MAC OSX?

Tags: c#, excel, vba, macos, class-library

I created this COM Visible DLL using c# that can be referenced from Excel VBA on Windows.

Some users in our office also use excel on their MAC OS and they usually open up the same file from our shared directory to run the code. Is it possible to create a class library for Excel on MAC that is COM visible?

If possible what is the best way to implement this?

Comment: There are a very large number of duplicates for this question.  Hard to pick the "best" when there are no happy answers.  Probably this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41172984/office-excel-com-interop-on-mac-osx-using-net-core

Comment: So this is not possible in any way even if I used another framework other than .net? @HansPassant

Comment: You will not get a happy answer, no matter how often asking the question seems useful to you.